# Odd behavior of random selection of exercises

Tags: exercises, exsheets

I'm testing some of the features of the `exsheets` package. Specifically I'm trying to use  `\includequestions[<options>]{<list of filenames>}` to include some random exercise from some external files. But I just get: `No pages of output`.

The code is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/lstc4bnreuyh52h/Rz-usORDPm).

Comment: It's better to provide a minimal example, rather than your current fragmented and diverse code/file set. Moreover, the link you provide might be dead later, implying that this question will not help others that much. So, include the code in a minimal example that we can compile on a local machine.

Comment: That's the bug I was telling you about in chat. It's fixed and I'll be uploading the new version to CTAN today.

Comment: In this case it is necessary to have external files. The external files should have enough `questions` otherwise it doesn't make sense to pick random questions. Thus the files are quite long. The folder will be stable. When I find some time I'll edit the questions to avoid images and then I'll add MWEs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a bug in `exsheets`. If no explicit IDs are given to the questions the option `random=<num>` to `\includequestions` currently selects *no* questions at all. Solution: either assign IDs to all questions, get the fixed version of `exsheets.sty` on the [bitbucket site](https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/exsheets/), or wait a few days until I uploaded it to CTAN and it is available in MiKTeX and TeX Live.

Comment: I've compiled the document in the above directory after update TeXLive. The random selection process only works with the first document. If I leave the two random selections it gives less than the expected questions.

Comment: @Leo Well, the random selection is everything but perfect right now :(. I know I need to work on it (and probably will change the (pseudo) random number generator at some point). Anyway, if you want to you can send me your test files so I can take a look.

Comment: The test files are in [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/lstc4bnreuyh52h/Rz-usORDPm). You can download the whole directory as a ZIP

Comment: @leo I reworked the random selection mechanism. It _seems_ to be more reliable now... I'd be glad if you would test the new version ([get it here](https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/exsheets/get/ac1faee36c0b.zip)) and could drop me a line if you still encounter problems or not.

Comment: Just tested it. It works fine. I was looking for packages to typeset exercises with the random selection feature. I decided choose your package so I'll use your package intensively for the next weeks. I'll let you know if I find something odd. Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear it :) Expect an official update in the next few days...